# SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E '@' not well managed when trying to develope a dialog answering with 'emails'

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm writing a Dialog that identifies some required capabilities and provides as output the name and the email of the person having those capabilities.

I wrote a dialog node that provides an output like this: `"The person you are looking for is name-surname and the email is xxxxx@yyyy.com"` , but if I run it I receive the following error `"SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E"`

The error disappear when replacing the `'@'`  in the answer with any other character

I also tried to build a context variable containing the email and building the answer using the variable but the error is the same.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the @ by adding \\ so it should be x\\@y.com

Comment: Just to clarify - `@` is a special character marking an entity so when used as a regular @ it needs to be escaped.